# How to add role to user in discord?

Tags: discord, discord.js

How can I add role to user in this case? I don't want to do this with roles.find.
Thanks for help!

**My script:**

```
const discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new discord.Client;

const prefix = "$"`;

client.on('message', function (message) {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args[0].toLowerCase();
  if (command === 'add') {
let member = message.member.guild.member(args[1])
client.cache.get(member.id).roles.add("roleid");

client.login('token');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:
use `args.shift()` to get a command, so then you can use `args` as command arguments

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '$';

client.on('message', function (message) {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    let command = args.shift();
    if (command === 'add') {
        if (args.length === 0) return message.reply('pls mention a member or write a ID');
        let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
        if (!member) return message.reply(`can't get a member ${args[0]}`);
        member.roles
            .add('ROLE ID')
            .then(() => {
                message.channel.send(`successfully add role to member ${member.user}`);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                message.channel.send(`Failed to add role to member`);
            });
    }
});
client.login('token');
```